# WordPress 'repairing database' in a constant error loop?

Tags: database

WordPress in a constant error loop.

When I try to log in I'm told to repair the databases.

Here is the sequence

1. Error reports: "One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired"
2. I follow the command which is to add this to my `wp-config.php` file `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);`
3. I do the above and the database is repaired, and as instructed I remove and command added above; try to log in and the loop continues...

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not without checking your database =) Do you have access to you database from the command line or perhaps from phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Don't have an answer of my own, but for anyone who appears here, there are some options to try on this page: https://www.scalahosting.com/kb/how-to-fix-wordpress-database-update-required-loop/

Answer (score 1):

You could try to repair all tables using the `mysqlcheck` command:

```
mysqlcheck --repair --databases <YOURDATABASE>
```

I would also try to disable any plugins and see if that solves the problem. Perhaps also switching to another theme.